# AttributeError: Word.Application.Documents with win32.com in a Flask application

Tags: angularjs, python-3.x, flask, win32com

I am developing a web application that takes a word file and performs tokenization. 
I noticed that the document is passed correctly from angularJS to Flask, but there is an error that I can't give an explanation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AOUP\MiniAnaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\AOUP\MiniAnaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\AOUP\MiniAnaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\AOUP\MiniAnaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\AOUP\MiniAnaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\AOUP\MiniAnaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 43, in tokenizer
    myDoc = word.Documents.Open(pathToProc, False, False, True) #stackoverflow
  File "C:\Users\AOUP\MiniAnaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Word.Application.Documents
```

The document is passed by `angularJS` with the following code:

```
var f = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].children[1].files[0].name;
if (f != ""){
    $http({
        url: '/tokenizeDoc', 
        method: "GET",
        params: {doc : f}
    });
}
```

Subsequently it is read by Flask with the following script, and the error falls in the line with the error comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import string
import win32com.client
import nltk
import os
from collections import Counter
from pywintypes import com_error
from flask import request, Flask, render_template, jsonify

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = False

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def landingPage():
    return render_template('homepage.html')

@app.route('/tokenizeDoc', methods = ['GET'])
def tokenizer():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pathToProc = request.values.get("doc")
        sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/italian.pickle')
        it_stop_words = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('italian') + ['\n', '\t', '']
        trashes = it_stop_words + list(string.punctuation)
        tokensTOT = []
        try:
            myDoc = word.Documents.Open(pathToProc, False, False, True) #ERROR!!!
            sentences = sent_tokenizer.tokenize(word.ActiveDocument.Range().Text)
            myDoc.Close()
            del myDoc
            for sentence in sentences:
                tokensTOT = tokensTOT + [t.lower() for t in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) 
                                         if t.lower() not in trashes]
        except com_error:
            print('IMPOSSIBILE DECIFRARE IL FILE')
        return ''
```

**I hope the win32com library is not incompatible with web frameworks and someone can give me an answer.**

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no line hilighted. Can you please also include the exception message

Comment: I entered the complete traceback and put the comment, rather than the highlight

Comment: Can you also include where `word` is defined

Comment: I put the whole script

Comment: @jan-seins let me know if you know anything about it...

Answer (score 0):

use `os.path.abspath(pathToProc)` instead of `pathToProc myDoc = word.Documents.Open(pathToProc, False, False, True) #ERROR!!!`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
The only solution that I managed to apply is to execute `win32com.client.Dispatch` individually for each call of the `view` function.

You also need to execute `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` for normal working flask multi-threading

```
import pythoncom
import win32com.client


def get_word_instance():
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    return win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")


@app.route('/tokenizeDoc', methods=['GET'])
def tokenizer():
    word = get_word_instance()
    word.visible = False
```

The creation instance of COM-object can be a resource-intensive process. If you need more performance when working with COM objects, then you may need to consider the option of disabling the multithreading of the Flask application.

```py
app.run(threaded=False)
```

Then you can use your code without any changes